# Handling large data on google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Im using python on google app engine to save data. Basically, location of a test device that has been logged over time. The data can be very large (as large as 702104) of length. The file is a json file and i basically iterate through the object, saving data in the data store.

```
class LocationObject(ndb.Model):
index = ndb.IntegerProperty()
lat = ndb.FloatProperty()
lng = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Having serious problem with this implementation. It runs into DeadLineError, as iterating through large data takes very long time. Also, I am saving data such way because i want to query for location and be able to get data in the server that matches search parameter.

How best can I handle such data without running into any of the issues stated.

Comment: look into datastore geolocation if you want to query by proximity. look into using cursors for large queries. your question is too broad to give an answer.

Comment: You haven't said if your deadline error is when you are writing large amounts of records or querying.  My guess is on writes.  If it's on the write phase, I suggest you save the whole object as a blob, and then use a task queue to write out the individual entities asynchronously.

Comment: Also first off look at how you are writing entities.  Are you doing it in a loop individually or in a single batch write.   You should probably show detail on what you are doing for more applicable advice.